# How can I select all data based on date range mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have a lists of records like below

```
[
  {
    "product": "p1",
    "salesdate": "2020-02-01",
    "amount": 100
  },
  {
    "product": "p2",
    "salesdate": "2020-02-04",
    "amount": 200
  },
  
]
```

On 2nd feb and 3rd feb i don't have data. But I need to add this in my result. My expected result is

```
[
  {
    "amount": 100,
    "salesdate": "2020-02-01"
  },
  {
    "amount": 0,
    "salesdate": "2020-02-02"
  },
  {
    "amount": 0,
    "salesdate": "2020-02-03"
  }
  {
    "amount": 200,
    "salesdate": "2020-02-04"
  }
]
```

Can I achieve this using mongoDB?

https://mongoplayground.net/p/EiAJdY9jRHn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$reduce` for it. Whenever one has to work with data/time values, then I recommend the [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) library. You don't have to use it, but it makes your life easier.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   // Put all data into one document
   { $group: { _id: null, data: { $push: "$$ROOT" } } },
   // Add missing days
   {
      $addFields: {
         data: {
            $reduce: {
               // Define the range of date
               input: { $range: [0, moment().get('day')] },
               initialValue: [],
               in: {
                  $let: {
                     vars: {
                        ts: {
                           $add: [moment().startOf('month').toDate(), { $multiply: ["$$this", 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24] }]
                        }
                     },
                     in: {
                        $concatArrays: [
                           "$$value",
                           [{
                              $ifNull: [
                                 { $first: { $filter: { input: "$data", cond: { $eq: ["$$this.salesdate", "$$ts"] } } } },
                                 // Default value for missing days
                                 { salesdate: "$$ts", amount: 0 }
                              ]
                           }]
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { $unwind: "$data" },
   { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$data" } }
   // If requried add further $group stages
])
```

Note, this code returns values from first day of **current** months to **current** day (not 2020 as in your sample data). You may adapt the ranges - your requirements are not clear from the question.

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aGtR4prMhSM)

Comment: The start date and end date is the input. In between these dates any date is missing I need to add that date with 0 amount this is my requirement

Comment: getting this error  fail to parse content of query: invalid character '.' after array element

Comment: Then you may have a typo. Adapting the ranges should be no challenge.  `moment().get('day')` is the number of days, i.e. you have to calculate the difference of your input values.

Comment: will you be able to create mongoplayground?

Comment: Added playground. Note, you should **never** store date/time values as string, it's a design flaw. Use always proper `Date` object as I did in the playground. Function [$dateFromString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/) will help you.